# an item of list is not being equal to one another

Tags: python

I am creating a project game which will include palindrome words
I have a list of all the words in english and I want to check every word in the list and find the ones equal to eachother

```
file1  = open ('words.txt')
file2reversed = open ('words.txt')
words = file1.readlines()



print(words[3][::-1])
print()
if words[3][::-1] == words[3]:
    print("equal")
else:
    print("not")
```

my code looks like this, I wrote the 3rd word as a palindrome word and wanted to check if it is working and the output looks like this

```
aaa
aaa

not
```

why is `words[3][::-1]` not equal to `words[3]` even if it is a palindrome word?

Comment: Not reproducible, `print('aaa'[::-1] == 'aaa')` gives True. Check for blank characters in your input

Comment: @wegry OP's code is using the `==` operator, which when used on strings (which these are) checks the content. not the `id`.

Comment: @wegry but `words[3]` would be a string not a list. That's not what happens here.

Comment: @matszwecja should be reproducible, newlines are preserved with `readlines`, so `'aaa\n' != '\naaa'`

Comment: @matszwecja I stand corrected, and am clearly spending too much time in JS.

Answer (score 1):

Use `file.read().splitlines()` instead. `file.readlines()` returns lines with a newline appended to each string at the end, so when reversed, `'\naaa' != 'aaa\n'`.

More cleanly

```py
file = open('words.txt')
text = file.read()
words = text.splitlines()

# words is a list of strings without '\n' at the end of each line.
```

Comment: It should be `file.read().splitlines()` instead: this method is for strings, not for files.

Comment: @SUTerliakov you are totally right.